# Cannot Open CSV File Swift

Tags: swift, csv

I am trying to create a simple CVS file in document directory on iPad or temp directory. This code is as follows:

```
 let fileName = "test.csv"

        _ = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
```

I am then trying to modify the file using CSV.swift library from github like this:

```
let stream = OutputStream(toFileAtPath: "test.csv", append: false)!

        let csv = try! CSVWriter(stream: stream) // Error at this line


        try! csv.write(row: headerarray)
        try! csv.write(row: dataarray)

        csv.stream.close()
```

For some reason I am getting error saying `CSV.CSVError.cannotOpenFile: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-802.0.53/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift`

It doesn't look like I am creating the .csv file correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are throwing away the path to the Temporary Directory in the second line. That is your problem. So instead of adding `fileName` inside the Temporary Directory, you are trying to add it to the root of your hard disk. I doubt you have permissions for this and therefore fail to create the file. Try building up the full pathname like I do in the first line of the function below.

Here is a function that writes a String to a file in the Temporary Directory using streams.

```
func streamTextToFile(_ text: String) {
  let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("test.csv")
  guard let stream = OutputStream(toFileAtPath: url.path, append: false) else { return }
  let data = [UInt8](text.utf8)
  stream.open()
  stream.write(data, maxLength: data.count)
  stream.close()
}
```

Here is some sample output.
[image]